# Umbraco 5 - GetMediaUrl in ChildAction View?

Tags: umbraco5

I have a ChildAction Macro using SurfaceController. In the view for this action I want to use GetMediaUrl.

Is this possible?

Comment: i am also searching for a way to use GetDictionaryItem helper in my SUrfaceController.